# WebRTC Video Stream Received but Not Playing

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io, webrtc

I have no idea what's going wrong with my app, everything seems like it should be working but just isnt. I want to make a simple facetime like app. I'm using a simple setup that serves an index.html file and and has websockets set up. The client connects to a room in socket.io and then they try to connect via RTCPeerConnnection. The recipient gets back the media stream object from the caller but when I add it on the video elements .srcObject property it just doesnt work, it'll infinitely load throwing no errors.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video autoplay id="me"></video>
    <video controls autoplay id="partner"></video>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    const initiator = (location.hash === "#initiator")? true: false;
    const socket = io("http://127.0.0.1:8000");

    if(!initiator){
        peer = new RTCPeerConnection();

        peer.onaddstream = stream=>{
            let video = document.getElementById("partner");
            video.srcObject = stream.stream;
            console.log(stream)
        }

        socket.emit("createRoom", "room");
        socket.on("roomCreated", ()=>{
            console.log("room made");
        });
        socket.on("startVideoRequest", remote=>{
            peer.setRemoteDescription(remote)
            .then(()=>{
               return peer.createAnswer()
            })
            .then(sdp=>{
                peer.setLocalDescription(sdp)
            })
            .then(()=>{
                socket.emit("acceptVideoRequest", {id: "room", sdp: peer.localDescription});
            })
            .catch(err=>{
                console.log(err);
            })
        });
    }else {
        socket.emit("joinRoom", "room");
        const peer = new RTCPeerConnection({
            initiator,
        });
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}).then(stream=>{
            peer.addStream(stream);
            peer.createOffer()
            .then(sdp=>{
                peer.setLocalDescription(sdp)
            })
            .then(()=>{
                socket.emit("startVideo", {id: "room", sdp: peer.localDescription});
            })
            .catch(err=>{
                console.log(err);
            })
        })
        socket.on("videoRequestAccepted", data=>{
            peer.setRemoteDescription(data);
        });
    }
</script>
</html>
```

index.js(server):

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const socketIO = require("socket.io");

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/index.html`)
});

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = socketIO(server);
let rooms = [];

io.on("connection", (socket)=>{
    console.log(rooms)
    socket.emit("getRooms", rooms);

    socket.on("disconnect", ()=>{
        console.log("disconnected")
        rooms = [];
    })

    socket.on("createRoom", (id)=>{
        socket.join(id);
        rooms.push(id);
        socket.emit('roomCreated');
    });

    socket.on("joinRoom", (id)=>{
        socket.join(id);
        io.to(id).emit('roomJoined');
    });

    socket.on("startVideo", ({id, sdp})=>{
        io.to(id).emit('startVideoRequest', sdp)
    });

    socket.on("acceptVideoRequest", ({id, sdp})=>{
        io.to(id).emit('videoRequestAccepted', sdp);
    })

});

server.listen(port, ()=>console.log("running"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably triping over the fact that autoplay on audio doesn't work.

To have it work, I do two things :

1. set muted
2. make sure the user has pressed a button on the page first

see https://github.com/pipe/two/blob/master/index.html#L73
for example code and
https://webrtchacks.com/autoplay-restrictions-and-webrtc/
for a discussion.

Comment: This this gives me the same result. I set the video to muted and wrapped the whole script in a button click event listener but the video still just loads and never plays.

Answer (score 0):

This element worked for me:

```
  <video id='localElement' playsInline muted autoPlay></video>
```

If you can console the video stream being received in the console then try this